# Start systemd service after specific service?

Tags: service, systemd

I have a general question. How does one start a systemd unit `*.service` after a particular `*.service` has started successfully?

More specific question is, how do I start `website.service` only after `mongodb.service` has started? In other words `website.service` should depend on `mongodb.service`.

Comment: This question belongs to ServerFault, no ?

Comment: @Rémi it's okay on both sites! :)

Comment: @AnonymousPenguin No, just it was like 3.5 years before you replied, it's not an on-topic question for SO. It's not about programming. SF or, better,  Unix/Linux.SE would be far more appropriate.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Possibly relevant ServerFault question: https://serverfault.com/questions/812492/systemd-automatically-start-restart-specific-systemd-service-after-another-ser

Answer (score 163, accepted):

In the .service file under the [Unit] section:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Website
After=syslog.target network.target mongodb.service
```

The important part is the `mongodb.service`

The manpage describes it however due to formatting it's not as clear on first sight

[systemd.unit - well formatted](http://web.archive.org/web/20150324001109/http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora20/man5/systemd.unit.5.html)

[systemd.unit - not so well formatted](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

Comment: Our mongod service starts a very large database. The subsequent service does not start correctly because it seems mongo takes more time to load the database after start. So our 2nd service starts but fails because mongo has started successfully but has not loaded the database. Maybe a delay could help...

Comment: Is it possible for systemd service to handle following scenerio .Consider multiple services A,B,C,D . If A exists I want B,C,D to start only after A else if A doesnt exist B,C,D may start in any order . Please help

Comment: @achilles Can you create a fake service A on the systems where A is not needed. In that way the dependencies of B, C, D can be kept simple.

Comment: The proper html documentation is here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Comment: The "well-formatted" manpage looks quite outdated. Shouldn't it be removed?

Answer (score 63):

`After=` dependency is only effective when service including `After=` and service included by `After=` are both scheduled to start as part of your boot up.

Ex:

```
a.service
[Unit]
After=b.service
```

This way, if both `a.service` and `b.service` are **enabled**, then systemd will order `b.service` after `a.service`.

If I am not misunderstanding, what you are asking is how to start `b.service` when `a.service` starts even though `b.service` is not enabled.

The directive for this is `Wants=` or `Requires=` under `[Unit]`.

```
website.service
[Unit]
Wants=mongodb.service
After=mongodb.service
```

The difference between `Wants=` and `Requires=` is that with `Requires=`, a failure to start `b.service` will cause the startup of `a.service` to fail, whereas with `Wants=`, `a.service` will start even if `b.service` fails.  This is explained in detail on [the man page of `.unit`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).

Comment: I believe the truth is the exact opposite of this answer. `After=website.service` means "execute my unit after website.service !". That's what is explained in the docs : ["After= ensures that the configured unit is started after the listed unit finished starting up"](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=). I'm assuming "listed units" are units on the right hand side of "After=".

Comment: "This way, if both a.service and b.service are enabled, then systemd will order b.service after a.service. " Don't you mean the other way around? `swap(a, b)`

Comment: @Sindarus In the same link you posted is proof this answer is correct. `After=` only comes into play when the services are started at the same time (such as bootup) otherwise `After=` is meaningless.  Add `Wants=` or `Requires=` to auto start another process. *Note that those settings are independent of and orthogonal to the requirement dependencies as configured by Requires=, Wants=, Requisite=, or BindsTo=. It is a common pattern to include a unit name in both the After= and Wants= options, in which case the unit listed will be started before the unit that is configured with these options.*