# Wayland start application after wayland starts

Tags: yocto, wayland

Hi I'm trying to sort of autostart an applocation in Wayland, so that it starts after the sesktop is visible. I can start it manually via ssh via openvt but the problem is it wont start if I add it for instance into a service.
It just crashes. Does any one know how to autostart an app like that?
I'm using Poky (yocto) 2.1.2 with renesas' meta-renesas bsp 2.19 wayland 1.11
Update:
To be more precise it is Yocto's Poky built for Renesas' R-Car with wayland as   manager. Poky 2.1.2

Comment: What kind of init system are you using? Its pretty easy to start a service after another with systemd. You could also just let it restart if it fails. Also i dont know about wayland but with X it was important to the the DISPLAY environment variable in the service file

Comment: I did that it starts after weston.service but it crashes. When I start it. It's more a matter of environmemt variables for weston I guess... when I login via uart console it has them e.g. XDG_RUNTIME_DIR when login via ssh it doesnt but then setting it manually and using openvt works I need to check if I used it service... but that will be tommorow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have finally figured it out what I was doing wrong.
Tu put it short I had to use `openvt` to start the application (and curiously some delay in seconds despite using `After=weston.service` ) and the applications started successfully.

Comment: yes it would make send to check weston pid if using weston-launch , I use this in my pinball project

Answer (score 0):

As `Fl0v0` mentions, it depends on which init system you use.

If you use `sysvinit`, you have to mention this in your script:

```
# Required-Start: <wayland service>
```

On systemd:

```
a.service
[Unit]
After=b.service
```

Original sources: [sysvinit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150343/how-can-this-init-script-start-without-its-dependency) and [systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830670/systemd-start-service-after-specific-service)

Comment: I'm doing it like that I start the app as a service I acutally see it starting and crashing I can't debug it though, the part that crashes is proprietary